# Spark DataFrame to Avro and Saving AVRO files to a Cassandra Table

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, apache-spark-sql, avro

I have a created a data frame in Spark and now want to save this in a user defined AVRO format and in turn saving it to a Cassandra table.

How to do it?

I have tried saving it to local AVRO files using this :

```
df.write().mode("append").format("com.databricks.spark.avro").save("/Users/xyz/AVRO Files/fifth");
```

Comment: Did you use spark-avro and cassandra-spark-connector? What's the issue(s)?

Comment: No I have not used these. I am just trying to get an idea, what should be the approach??

Small piece of code would be very helpful.

Comment: why not save directly to cassandra?

Comment: My scenario is that I have to send the Avro files back to another Kafka topic.. so trying to save the same files in Cassandra as well

Answer (score 0):

```
df.write()
.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
.mode("append")
.save()
```

you will need spark-cassandra-connector to write dataframe to cassandra.

Comment: is there any way to first convert the data frame into a user defined AVRO format??